# Make a range to know if it's current, is past or is futur event mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an `event` collection with some attributes, in particular `start` and `end`, which are dates.

How can I know with a query if it's past, current, or future?

Anybody have an idea? I've been stuck on this problem for 1 day...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to find events that are in the future, past, or present? Or are you trying to find out if an event you are querying is past, present, or future?

If it is the first, It's fairly simple to use the $gt, $gte, $lt or $lte operators in your query.

```
var now = new Date()
// future events:
db.events.find({start: {$gt: now}});

// current events:
db.events.find({start: {$lte: now}, end: {gte: new Date()}});

// past events
db.events.find({end: {lt: now}});
```

MongoDB allows for comparisons with dates.

If it is the latter, you will need to find your events, and then parse the dates in your code.

Also, make sure to set indexes on your end/start dates, to ensure quick lookups:

```
db.events.ensureIndex({start: 1});
db.events.ensureIndex({end: 1});
```

Comment: sorry i'm tired i forgot the now :) just an another question. I want to know if the event is tomorrow : how can i add 1 day (or more) to querying if the event start tomorrow ? thanks

Comment: i'm new in mongo, why the index is important ? and how can i set it ? thanks a lot

Comment: did the index is for document attr for query to improve it ?

Comment: Yes, indexing indexes on keys in your documents makes for very quick queries. The last code in my response is the code to set up indexes.

Comment: awesome ! i read some article in that ! thanks you very much !